# async / wait in nested functions

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise, wait

I'm trying to display a nested countdown, implemented in two nested loops.

The full, working code can be found in this [js.fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/utw9sr86/1/). Two relevant parts are the following:

```
function sleep(ms) 
{
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function main()
{
    while(true)
    {
      clearScreen();

        for (var i = 10; i > 0; i--) 
        {
            print(i);

            await sleep(1000);

            clearScreen();

            for (var j = 3; j > 0; j--) 
            {
                print(j);

                await sleep(1000);

                clearScreen();
            }
        }
    }
}

main();
```

This works as expected. However, when I try to refactor the most inner loop into a seperate function like this

```
async function innerLoop()
{
    for (var j = 3; j > 0; j--) 
    {
        print(j);

        await sleep(1000);

        clearScreen();
    }
}
```

and call this function inside `main()` the coutndown doesn't work as expected. (Corresponding code: [js.fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/utw9sr86/)).

How can I make async / await work when using it inside nested functions to implememt this? I want to avoid having everything in one big function.

Comment: I hope You're calling it as: `await innerLoop()`

Comment: uh oh, I thought I had tested that... thanks!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4wcyLtrp/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`innerLoop()` is an `async` function so you need to `await` it on your call:

```js
var containerElement = document.getElementById("container");

function print(string) {
  var textDiv = document.createElement("div");
  textDiv.textContent = string;

  containerElement.appendChild(textDiv);
}

function clearScreen() {
  containerElement.textContent = "";
}

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function main() {
  while (true) {
    clearScreen();

    for (var i = 10; i > 0; i--) {
      print(i);

      await sleep(1000);

      clearScreen();

      await innerLoop();  // <-- Await innerLoop()
    }
  }
}

async function innerLoop() {
  for (var j = 3; j > 0; j--) {
    print(j);

    await sleep(1000);

    clearScreen();
  }
}

main()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <div id="container"></div>

</body>

</html>
```